# How to execute 2 Store Procedures with conditions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to RUN SP2 inside SP1. The SP2 inserts several data into a table, one of those data is actual date.

So, i want that SP2 only execute if in the column date, the date is within the last 10 days.

It´s possible?

Thanks

Comment: yes - not sure how a date you insert is not an actual date, but ok. you just need to compare your 'column date' value to SYSDATE, an diff is within 10/11, then exec sp2 from sp1

Comment: if my comment isn't clear, i'm suggesting you do this with the pl/sql code you're writing in in SP1 - not anything you're doing at execution time in SQL Developer

Comment: Something like this?                                                                                      IF(SELECT [My_Col] FROM [My_Tbl]) < DATEADD(day, -15, SYSDATE)
    THEN execute SP_2()
    END IF;

Comment: It would be better if you attempted this, and then posted your full pl/sql code as part of the question, with specific questions - then we can help...better.

Comment: can´t understand what you mean: "if my comment isn't clear, i'm suggesting you do this with the pl/sql code you're writing in in SP1 - not anything you're doing at execution time in SQL Developer"

Comment: I'm saying you tagged this as a sql-developer question, i'm saying it's a pl/sql question

Comment: so, have to open another post, right?

Comment: No, but i would change your question to show what you've tried

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

First, create a table and insert some sample rows:

```
SQL> create table my_tbl
  2    (id      number,
  3     my_col  date
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_tbl (id, my_col)
  2    -- more than 10 days ago
  3    select 1, date '2018-05-25' from dual union all
  4    -- less than 10 days ago
  5    select 2, date '2018-09-01' from dual;

2 rows created.
```

Create two procedures; SP_1 is supposed to call SP_2 if condition is met. I'm looping through both rows in the table; one row's date value is OK, another one isn't.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp_2 as
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line('...I am in SP_2 now');
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure sp_1 as
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select my_col from my_tbl order by id) loop
  4      dbms_output.put_line('date value = ' || to_char(cur_r.my_col, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
  5      if cur_r.my_col >= trunc(sysdate) - 10 then
  6         dbms_output.put_line('...calling SP_2');
  7         sp_2;
  8      else
  9         dbms_output.put_line('...date condition failed - not calling SP_2');
 10      end if;
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    sp_1;
  3  end;
  4  /
date value = 2018-05-25
...date condition failed - not calling SP_2
date value = 2018-09-01
...calling SP_2
...I am in SP_2 now

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```